# Label element changing and animation in foreach loop

Tags: c#, label

I am trying to make simple data transfer to database with animation. I succeed to animating progress bar but my percent label did not changed value and animation.
My code is below:

```
pBar.Maximum = query.Count( ); //pBar is progress bar
foreach ( var cell in query )
{
    pBar.Value++;
    lblYuzde.Text = "%" + ( pBar.Value / pBar.Maximum ) * 100; //lblYuzde is label
    Application.DoEvents( );
    //Do events
}
```

Progress bar is good working with animaton, but label is not change. What is my mistake?

Comment: when you use the debugger to step through the code, what value is the `lblYuzde.Text` when you pass this line in the first iteration.
`lblYuzde.Text = "%" + ( pBar.Value / pBar.Maximum ) * 100;` you need to convert the integer value to a string if you want to represent the value in a `Text` property. use the debugger and you will easily be able to fix this simple mistake. also try not using `Application.DoEvents()` you could probably obtain better results using a `BackgroundWorker` plenty of examples of this are online as well.

Comment: Your posted code should result in your label going straight to %100.  You have nothing to slow it down to actually show any processing.  Avoid that Application.DoEvents and use a BackgroundWorker, as suggested.

Comment: @MethodMan I'm sure this would work, `"string" + 12` results in `"string12"`. The problem here seems to be integer division: Since `pBar.Value` is always smaller than `pBar.Maximum` the division is always `0`. The correct way would be `"%" + (100 * pBar.Value / pBar.Maximum)`. Anyway, doing this in a loop and calling `Application.DoEvents` is a bad way. Think about using a timer or an async method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation only has integer values your result could not be right.

You have to cast one of the values to double.

```
lblYuzde.Text = "%" + ( (double)pBar.Value / pBar.Maximum ) * 100; //lblYuzde is label
```

EDIT:
For more information see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to add line

```
foreach(...)
{
  ...
  lblYuzde.Refresh();// or lblYuzde.Invalidate();
}
```